# Yosemite SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled

Tags: osx-yosemite

Since installation of Yosemite I keep getting error SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled. It occurs with every https url in Terminal.
Can't find how to fix this, any suggestions ?
thanks 
Frank

Answer (score 8):

For others coming here trying to figure out why they are running into this issue with Wordpress and maybe also WooCommerce and are on OS X Yosemite then you will want to follow Asaph/Cupcake's answer to "osx 10.10 Curl POST to HTTPS url gives SSLRead() error" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538127)

Basically the issue is cURL is using Apple's SecureTransport instead of OpenSSL. The linked to answer will walk you through testing the SSL Version and then fixing it.

One caveat I ran into is I had already installed php 5.5.21 via homebrew but my system was not using it. I unlinked 5.5.21 by doing "brew unlink php55

Answer (score -1):

I found a wrong setting in my `.gitconfig`, in the `[http]` section. I added `sslVerify=false`and deleted the other settings in this section, and it fixed my problem.

Comment: What was it, I'm having the same issue in Yosemite but in PHP curl

Comment: I edited my .gitconfig file -> change the [http] section : add "sslVerify=false" and delete the other settings in this section.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this without setting sslVerify to false?

Comment: This fixed my problem as well. Had the exact same problem.