# Bower SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled

Tags: git, ssl, bower, osx-yosemite

I have an issue on my macbook with Bower when ever it tries to install something and tries to acces git, I get errors like this:

```
Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads   https://github.com/any-repo-here.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize.git/': SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled
```

However, executing the failing command on the prompt :

```
git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/any-repo-here.git
```

works just fine so I assume it has something to do with Bower.

Note:
I am aware I can fix this problem by instructing git to use git:// insteadOf https:// through gitignore but that means my normal git operations no longer work so I'd have to change back and forth all the time which is a pain...

Comment: Does this answer work? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26711716/893780

Comment: Nope.. setting sslVerification to false (or true for that matter) doesn't make a difference.