# How do I get RCurl to connect to POST SSL on OS X Yosemite?

Tags: r, macos, libcurl, osx-yosemite, rcurl

Since upgrading to OS X Yosemite 10.10.2, I have been unable to use RCurl to send POSTs via SSL. The error message I get is:

```
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) :
    SSLRead() return error -9806
```

This strongly resembles the curl error here: [osx 10.10 Curl POST to HTTPS url gives SSLRead() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/osx-10-10-curl-post-to-https-url-gives-sslread-error)

So I ran the instructions to install libcurl via home-brew, per the answers on that question, but I cannot figure out how to link RCurl to the new libcurl.  curl-config still returns the old installation of libcurl.

```
> packageVersion("RCurl") 
[1] ‘1.95.4.5’

> version 
platform x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 
arch x86_64 
os darwin13.4.0 
system x86_64, darwin13.4.0 
status 
major 3 
minor 1.2 
year 2014 
month 10 
day 31 
svn rev 66913 
language R 
version.string R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) 
nickname Pumpkin Helmet
```

Comment: What do you get from `which curl` in a Terminal session. It should be `/usr/bin/curl`. I'm guessing you build a new curl with a nonstandard location and R packages are looking for it in the wrong directory.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that - the binary version on CRAN works fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out!

First, I installed brew from homebrew:

```
brew install --with-libressl curl
```

Then, I copied the curl-config in place:

```
sudo cp /usr/bin/curl-config /usr/bin/curl-config.bak
sudo cp /usr/local/opt/curl/bin/curl-config /usr/bin/curl-config
```

Then, I reinstalled RCurl:

```
install.packages("RCurl", type="source")
```

And it worked again.