# How to install RProtoBuf in R

Tags: r, protocol-buffers

When I tried to install RProtoBuf in R `install.packages("RProtoBuf")`, I have the following error message at the end of the installation

Testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘RProtoBuf’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):  
 unable to load shared object '/home/cloud/anaconda3/envs/acumos/lib/R/library/00LOCK-RProtoBuf/00new/RProtoBuf/libs/RProtoBuf.so':
  /home/cloud/anaconda3/envs/acumos/lib/R/library/00LOCK-RProtoBuf/00new/RProtoBuf/libs/RProtoBuf.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK6google8protobuf10Reflection17GetRepeatedUInt64ERKNS0_7MessageEPKNS0_15FieldDescriptorEi

Error: loading failed  
Execution halted  
ERROR: loading failed

#removing ‘/home/cloud/anaconda3/envs/acumos/lib/R/library/RProtoBuf’
#restoring previous ‘/home/cloud/anaconda3/envs/acumos/lib/R/library/RProtoBuf’

Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘RProtoBuf’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in   ‘/tmp/Rtmpfj6wQF/downloaded_packages’ 
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library' 
Making 'packages.html' ... done  , than
```

My configuration here :

OS : ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS xenial
conda : 4.7.10
anaconda navigator 1.9.7
R : 3.6.1
RStudio : 99.9.9
libprotoc 3.8.0

- I installed protobuf thanks to : https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md? that solved some other issues.
- I tried ./configure --prefix=/usr as explained in https://www.oipapio.com/question-2872905? but it doesn't work

I just expect to have RProtoBuf installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481435/installation-of-package-rcurl-had-non-zero-exit-status)

Comment: Hi, finally I succeeded to install RProtoBuf. I removed conda, remove protobuf reinstall R, and install protobuf thanks to :  sudo apt-get install   protobuf-compiler protobuf-c-compiler libprotobuf-c-dev libprotobuf-dev libprotoc-dev. then now insatll.packages("RProtoBuf") is successfull