# How to add product image via the woocommerce REST API?

Tags: php, api, curl, woocommerce

I am working with the Woocommerce REST API and need to add a product to the store.

It worked before. Now I have this error:

```
stdClass Object ( [errors] => Array ( 
  [0] => stdClass Object ( [code] => 
  woocommerce_api_invalid_remote_product_image 
  [message] => Error getting remote image 
  https://www.google.lt/images/srpr/logo11w.png ) ) )
```

Here is the documentation for adding a product via the WooCommerce REST API
 http://woothemes.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#create-a-product

Here is my code:

```
$dataArray = array(
            'title' => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
            'description' => 'description1',
            'price' => '69',
            'sku' => 'sku2',
            'tags' => 'tag1, tag2, tag3',
            'color' => array('red', 'blue'),
            'size' => array('S', 'M'),
            'image' => 'https://www.google.lt/images/srpr/logo11w.png'
            );

public function addProduct($data)
{
    $wc_api = $this->_getClient();


    $newProductData = array(
        'product' => array(
            'title' => $data['title'],
            'type' => 'variable',
            'regular_price' => $data['price'],
            'description' => $data['description'],
            'sku' => $data['sku'],
            'tags' => [ $data['tags'] ],
            'images' => [ array('src' => $data['image'], 'position' => '0') ],
            'virtual' => true
        )
    );

    return $wc_api->create_product($newProductData);
}
```

I'm using this client to call the REST API

https://github.com/kloon/WooCommerce-REST-API-Client-Library

EDITED:
If I get image from wordpress where woocommerce is hosted then all is fine. But, if I use a link from another site then I get an error.

Comment: The extrenal images will be get using `wp_remote_get()`. Do you have cURL installed? Or something blocking extrenal requests?

Comment: "curl is enabled". Cool, but is configured correctly? Have you tested external requests?

Comment: If you can debug the server side, take a look at what's happening inside `class-wc-api-products.php` around line 1700. That's what's generating the error. You may be experiencing SSL errors. Have you tried it with an `http` link rather thank `https`? See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/curl-post-to-https-url-returns-sslread-error

Comment: I'm pretty certain that `image['position']` should be an integer too, though that doesn't seem to be throwing the error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue and the error that cURL was generating inside WordPress which leads to `woocommerce_api_invalid_remote_product_image` was `{"errors":{"http_request_failed":["SSLRead() return error -9806"]},"error_data":[]}` which means, according to Asaph in https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538127/266531,

> php is compiled with a version of cURL that uses Apple's Secure
>   Transport under Yosemite and the target of the URL request doesn't
>   support SSLv3 (which was probably disabled due to the POODLE
>   vulnerability).

My guess is that you are experiencing errors with using SSL over cURL.

Have you tried it with an `http` link rather thank `https`?

If you can debug the server side, take a look at what's happening inside `class-wc-api-products.php` around line 1700. That's what's generating the error. You may be experiencing SSL errors.

If it is the same type of SSL issue, then your possible solutions are

1. Use a non-secure image link (`http` instead of `https`), or
2. Follow Asaph's steps to install PHP using OpenSSL instead of SecureSSL in his answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538127/266531

Answer (score 2):

In  Woocommerce REST API liblary You can also set option to dont validate SSL.

```
$options = array(
    'debug'           => true,
    'return_as_array' => false,
    'validate_url'    => false,
    'timeout'         => 60,
    'ssl_verify'      => false,
);
```