# Git Clone Fails with sslRead() error on OS X Yosemite

Tags: git, curl, openssl, osx-yosemite, gitlab

I'm currently on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3, and trying to git clone an existing repo which works fine on Windows.  I've tried a combo of installing git through homebrew with curl/openssl with no luck.  When i run the git clone, i get the following ssl read error:

```
GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone http://myURL/gitlab/project/project.git

> remote: Counting objects: 1641, done. remote: Compressing objects:
> 100% (1588/1588), done.
> * SSLRead() return error -98061641), 136.73 MiB | 1.71 MiB/s    
> * Closing connection 2 remote: Total 1641 (delta 910), reused 0 (delta 0) error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200 Receiving objects:
> 100% (1641/1641), 137.48 MiB | 1.64 MiB/s, done. Resolving deltas:
> 100% (910/910), done.
```

I've tried using both the Https & Http with no luck. Has anyone else hit something similar to this?

Below are outputs of git, curl, & openssl versions if that helps.

```
curl --version
curl 7.37.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin14.0) libcurl/7.37.1 SecureTransport zlib/1.2.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS GSS-Negotiate IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz 

git --version
git version 2.4.1

openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zd 8 Jan 2015
```

Thanks in advance for any direction!

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/curl-post-to-https-url-returns-sslread-error) may be useful.

Comment: *`http://myURL/gitlab/project/project.git`* - Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Comment: Thanks for the input, unfortunately i cannot post the exact URL its a private repo :(.  However, it is a gitlab instance with a standard repo nothing special.  I was able to clone from this repo on Windows and other OS's, for some reason just not Yosemite.

Comment: JavaBrett - Your link got me close to the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Javabrett's link got me to the answer, it revolves around Yosemite using an incorrect SSL dependency, which Git ends up using.

Installing Git via homebrew with these flags works:

```
brew install git --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl
```

Or:

```
brew reinstall git --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl
```

Comment: You may also need `curl` with `--with-openssl` option (on OS X 10.11 fresh install).

Comment: I needed to uninstall and reinstall BOTH git and curl with the options above. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

if one had no brewed openssl before the **answer above** (`brew reinstall git --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl`) **does not work**.

The workflow described [here](https://gist.github.com/entropiae/a899d8a78dc8a38f505e) does better:

```
$ brew remove git
$ brew remove curl

$ brew install openssl
$ brew install --with-openssl curl
$ brew install --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl git
```

Answer (score 2):

Just installing git with "brew install git --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl" didn't help.

I got resolved by setting 2 remote URL with any protocol https:// or ssh://.

1. upstream for team repo
2. origin for fork repo

Now, I am able to push with my changes to origin without any problem.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

If your are using a Virtul machine, then it is a connection problem.
To solve this issue, you have to go to VM settings to Bridge the physical connection.

VMware Player-->Removable Devices-->Network Adapter-->settings

You will find Network connection and check both

Bridged: Connected directly to the physical network

Replicate physical network connection state(if you are using a laptop).

Check following link for detail:

https://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-9/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.ws.using.doc%2FGUID-826323AD-D014-475D-8909-DFA73B5A3A57.html