# Git clone fails with "SSLRead() return error -980641"

Tags: git, macos, curl

I'm trying to clone a project from an open git repo. I got this error. I was trying to find out the reason and found [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385939/git-clone-fails-with-sslread-error-on-os-x-yosemite). Running `brew install git --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl` got this:

```
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
Error: Failed to download resource "git"
```

git --version: 2.4.9 (Apple Git-60
curl -V: curl 7.43.0`

Comment: That error message is from a curl powered by darwinssl and not OpenSSL which you make it sound like you're trying to use?

Comment: successfully cloned project using Tunnel Bear, but still have no idea what is the reason of this error...

Comment: You may also need to install `curl` with `--with-openssl` option via brew. It helps me on OS X 10.11 (fresh install).

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
$ brew remove git
$ brew remove curl

$ brew install openssl
$ brew install --with-openssl curl
$ brew install --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl git
```