# Unable to setup pods (error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806)

Tags: git, macos, cocoapods

```
Last login: Sun Sep 11 13:24:10 on ttys002
Deepanshus-MacBook-Air:~ deepanshusrivastava$ pod setup --verbose

Setting up CocoaPods master repo

Cloning spec repo `master` from `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` (branch `master`)
  $ /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master
  Cloning into 'master'...
  error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806
  fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
  fatal: early EOF
  fatal: index-pack failed
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git master

Cloning into 'master'...
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

This happens every time I try to install pods.
Badly Stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I am having same error for Cocoapods $pod install

This happens with curl used by SecureTransport backend. You may find some explanation of this error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36018543/6942920)

I have tried many many other ways to resolve and at one point, I used Tunnel Bear VPN to resolve this. I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34394947/6942920) for answer. But now, I found this is the [best way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40038126/6942920).

```
$ brew remove git
$ brew remove curl


$ brew install openssl
$ brew install --with-openssl curl
$ brew install --with-brewed-curl --with-brewed-openssl git
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the path to your version of Xcode is broken.
You can fix it With:

`sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

If you installed multiple versions of Xcode，You need to replace `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer` with the actual location of your Xcode.app like `/Applications/Xcode 7.3.1.app/Contents/Developer`.