# How to resolve "SSLRead() return error -9841" error in source tree

Tags: atlassian-sourcetree

I am getting

> SSLRead() return error -9841

error whenever I try top perform any action like - fetch, checkout in source tree.

Any pointers would help. Thanks.

Comment: On what OS is this?

Comment: @GinoMempin Mac OS Sierra version 10.12.6

Comment: If you run the git commands on a terminal, does it work OK? Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385939/git-clone-fails-with-sslread-error-on-os-x-yosemite? (it's for a different macOS version though)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, in my case was because my pal had changed the name of the project back in the repo. Then I was pointing to the old one. I solved it like this:

1. Go to my repo an copy the HTTPS URL on the clone option
2. Update the new URL destination with this command:

   ```
   git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
   ```

And it worked just fine, you can find more info about changing remote URLs in [here](https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue -9841.

I fixed it using `git config http.sslVerify true`.

You can check `http.sslverify` using this `git config --global --list`