# Use OpenSSL with PHP cURL in Mac OSX

Tags: php, macos, ssl, curl

I notice that when I run curl_version() in PHP on my local Mac server (OSX Yosemite), I get `"ssl_version = SecureTransport"`. [There seems to be an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/osx-10-10-curl-post-to-https-url-gives-sslread-error) with SecureTransport sending a POST request over SSL, so I'd like to use OpenSSL with cURL in PHP instead.

How can I change the version of SSL that cURL uses in PHP? If I run `php -i | grep "SSL Version"` from the command line, I get `SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.2d`, which is different from when run in cURL in PHP, which is puzzling.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/osx-10-10-curl-post-to-https-url-gives-sslread-error/26538127#26538127