# osx10.11.1 install cocoapods success but setup failed

Tags: cocoapods, rpc

After execution of `sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods`
I try to setup it and execute `pod setup`, after wait a long time, it gives me this error:
[image]

Anybody has the same fatal error with me?
I don't know what can I do now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [osx 10.10 Curl POST to HTTPS url gives SSLRead() error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/osx-10-10-curl-post-to-https-url-gives-sslread-error)

Answer (score 0):

I success this morning. Actully I do nothing to fix this issue， maybe it is the network's problem. I do it this morning before the office hours，and it download the spec fast from the github and install and setup completed success.