# How can I use OpenSSL instead of SecureTransport on OSX 10.11.6 with Apache PHP

Tags: php, macos, apache, ssl, curl

I recently upgraded up version of PHP on my Mac from the default on El Capitan to 7.1. Since doing that, when I am attempting to make a request to a locally hosted web service I am getting the following error:
`cURL error 35: SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled`. The service makes a curl request to a web page where the service interprets it and produces some data.

I think that I have tracked the error down to the fact that the SSL Version being used by PHP is `SecureTransport`. When I make the same requests to the same service hosted on an Ubuntu machine, there is no problems. The SSL Version being used on this machine is `OpenSSL/1.0.2g`.

I have tried using [osx 10.10 Curl POST to HTTPS url gives SSLRead() error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/osx-10-10-curl-post-to-https-url-gives-sslread-error/26538127#26538127) and https://www.farces.com/wikis/naked-server/php/php-7-openssl/ to try and get my local version of PHP to use OpenSSL and neither have been entirely successful. When I run `php -i | grep "SSL Version"` in my terminal, I get `SSL Version => OpenSSL/1.0.2j` but looking at `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, I still get `SSL Version  SecureTransport`.

Without throwing anymore aimless commands at my machine, is there a simple why that I can get the Apache version of PHP to also use OpenSSL instead of SecureTransport?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using plain curl on macOS and get the same error. `curl -l https://www.ferrari.com`.
The solution is to install curl with openSSL using home brew.

```
brew install openssl-curl
```

Then you need to use this version of curl and build php yourself.

Try this one:

```
brew uninstall php56 && brew install php56 --with-homebrew-curl
```

Comment: now that php moved to brew core, this no longer works  :(

Comment: 2019 solution: brew install curl-openssl