# SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled - Mac OS Sierra

Tags: git, ssl, github, macos-sierra

I upgraded my Mac OS to Sierra. After upgrading, when I tried to do `npm install` I get the following error:

**ECMDERR Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git", exit code of #128 fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-animate.git/': SSL: CA certificate set, but certificate verification is disabled**

I have written a script wherein

> npm install

also includes

> bower install

I have tried few possible solutions to fix the error, but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I would try reinstalling your modules and / or node

Comment: does it not have anything to do with github ?

Comment: Perhaps not.  Might be how the module pulls dependencies.  I didn't put this is an answer because I'm not saying it *will* work, but given the info you gave, that's where I'd start

Comment: i tried removing node modules and node and re-installing node v7.0.0
But it still gives the same error on npm install! :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538127/6309), it means Git is using a cURL based on [Apple's Secure Transport](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/Reference/secureTransportRef/), and the target of the URL request (GitHub) doesn't support SSLv3 (which was probably disabled due to the [POODLE exploit](https://www.openssl.org/%7Ebodo/ssl-poodle.pdf)).
This is true for GitHub since [October 2014](https://developer.github.com/changes/2014-10-16-removed-ssl-version-3-support-from-webhooks-and-services/)

You need to [install curl and Git with openssl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26538127/6309)

```
brew install --with-openssl curl
brew install git --with-brewed-curl
```

Comment: Woow! you save my day. I´ve been trying to fix this since days. So obscure problem! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @VonC. I can't thank you enough for this. I literally was pulling my hair. My Git-FTP won't work, no matter what changes I made, except for this where I had to uninstall curl and git both and reinstall with above commands and finally make it to work. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @Rahi Great! I am glad this answer is still helpful.