# SSLRead() return error -9806404

Tags: php, macos, curl, secure-transport

I have been stuck with a localhost issue for a while, i believe i have tried everything.

PHP CURL returns SSLRead() return error -9806404, when i attempt to CURL a https site.

I have tried to update the OS, reinstall apache, reinstall php, reinstall openssl, there is no info on the internet about this error.

I am running OS X Sierra, PHP 7.1, Apache/2.4.25, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017

Comment: -9806404 looks like an Apple SecureTransport error code; not an OpenSSL error code. In fact, `-9806404` is `FFFFFFFFFF6A5DBC`, and its not a properly formatted OpenSSL error. `openssl errstr 0xFFFFFFFFFF6A5DBC` returns `error:FFFFFFFFFF6A5DBC:lib(255):func(1701):reason(3516)`. But checkout these results: [securetransport curl "-9806"](https://www.google.com/search?q=securetransport+curl+"-9806").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [osx 10.10 Curl POST to HTTPS url gives SSLRead() error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/osx-10-10-curl-post-to-https-url-gives-sslread-error)