# Git push error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806

Tags: git, github

The error appear after `git push`, I use Github repo.

```
Counting objects: 16, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (14/14), done.
Writing objects: 100% (16/16), 12.26 MiB | 5.11 MiB/s, done.
Total 16 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
error: RPC failed; curl 56 SSLRead() return error -9806
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Everything up-to-date
```

It's difference with `github - git push fails: RPC failed; result=22, HTTP code = 411` ... and soon on.

This is my `.gitignore`

```
[http]
  postBuffer = 524288000

[https]
  postBuffer = 524288000
```

I search lot of solve, but not one fix it. Thanks for every help.

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/osx-10-10-curl-post-to-https-url-gives-sslread-error?

Comment: @Leonardo Hammer, Are you using `HTTPS` or `SSH` for connecting to github.

Comment: I use GPG sign and verify tags and commits to Github. I tried use SourceTree push three times and then, push successful. This is a strange problem with me.