# php curl headers do not return from website?

Tags: php, php-curl

I use this command to get headers back from this specific page.

```
curl -I https://www.gearbest.com/mobile-phones/pp_1686789.html?wid=1817324
```

i run the above command from terminal and i get these results...

```
HTTP/2 200
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
pragma: public
last-modified: Fri, 02 Nov 2018 18:15:13 GMT
gbcdnlang: en
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET, POST
ng-cache: HIT
x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt: 36
x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency: 137
cache-control: public, max-age=60
expires: Fri, 02 Nov 2018 23:39:15 GMT
date: Fri, 02 Nov 2018 23:38:15 GMT
set-cookie: ORIGINDC=3;Domain=.gearbest.com;Path=/
set-cookie: ORIGINDCPC=3;Domain=.gearbest.com;Path=/
set-cookie: AKAM_CLIENTID=d51abedb38c60f8a5217ae15808769fc; expires=Mon, 31-Dec-2038 23:59:59 GMT; path=/; domain=.gearbest.com
vary: User-Agent
```

So far so good. But when i try to implement in php using the code below i get "URL not exists" ! What am i doing wrong? Any help appreciated.

```
  $url1 = "https://www.gearbest.com/mobile-phones/pp_1686789.html?wid=1817324";
  $curl1 = curl_init($url1);
  curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
  curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
  curl_setopt($curl1, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5); //timeout in seconds


  $result1 = curl_exec($curl1);

  if ($result1 !== false)
  {
    $statusCode1 = curl_getinfo($curl1, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ($statusCode1 == 404)
    {
      echo "URL Not Exists";
    }
    else
    {
       echo "URL Exists";
    }
  }
  else
  {
    echo "URL not Exists";
  }
```

Comment: what you get if you type on the terminal `$ php -i | grep "SSL Version"` ?

Comment: Hello In terminal i get SSL Version => LibreSSL/2.0.20

Comment: The problem is LibreSSL. See my answer...

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the code you posted is valid. You don't need to alter it.

If you just try it with ex. `https://www.google.com` it works.

The problem is that your version of PHP uses **LibreSSL** for php-curl HTTPS connections.

I have the same issue on macOS where my version of PHP uses **OpenTransport**.

The website you're connecting to requires to establish a SSL connection in a way that **LibreSSL** is not able to handle.

You need to compile/install **OpenSSL** and run your code on a PHP interpreter that has been compiled to use it for php-curl.

---

**Update:**

as you're on macOS you may compile PHP from source.
Googling for `macos compile php from source` will return a list of "recipes" to do that.

If you use **brew** to compile PHP (and all the "web applications stack") you may take a look here:

[**osx 10.10 Curl POST to HTTPS url gives SSLRead() error**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461966/osx-10-10-curl-post-to-https-url-gives-sslread-error)

The question (and answer) also address a problem similar to the one in your question.

Comment: I am on MacOS too. So i have to install OpenSSL but then i have to find a tutorial how to do the rest of the procedure...

Comment: @stefanosn see the update on my answer. hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the guide i appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER option, it connects via SSl but checks the certificate, like this:

```
<?PHP
  $handle=curl_init('https://www.google.com');
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
  $content = curl_exec($handle);
  echo $content;
?>
```

Comment: i tried it but i get Error:LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60 on this page https://www.gearbest.com/mobile-phones/pp_1686789.html?wid=1817324 . It works on https://www.gearbest.com but not in a specific product page!

Answer (score 0):

I think that is not your problem. I think they block something when it's requested over PHP. When you use `file_get_contents` you get the following output.

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL: Operation timed out in /test.php on line 2
Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.gearbest.com/mobile-phones/pp_1686789.html?wid=1817324): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!  in /test.php on line 2
```

When you use the following url in your script it's working fine (`https://www.test.de`).

I have made some other tests with your script but i get everytime a result and your excepted result.

Comment: Error:LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 60 ... i am just curious how is this possible! There has to be a way!