# Php script that works in fetching og:image from url but fails on specific ones

Tags: php, arrays, powershell, openssl, facebook-opengraph

Hello i'm trying to build a custom script in php that fetches the og:image property in an array and then printout the specific result. I've used the following code

```
<?php
$_URL = $_GET['url']; //getting the url from THE url value
function getSiteOG( $url, $specificTags=0 ){
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url));
    $res['title'] = $doc->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue;
    foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $m){
        $tag = $m->getAttribute('name') ?: $m->getAttribute('property');
        if(in_array($tag,['description','keywords']) || strpos($tag,'og:')===0) $res[str_replace('og:','',$tag)] = $m->getAttribute('content');
    }
    return $specificTags? array_intersect_key( $res, array_flip($specificTags) ) : $res;
}
$_ARRAY = getSiteOG("$_URL");
echo $_ARRAY['image'];
?>
```

and when used with the following syntax e.g. on the our site

```
tags.php?url=http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

it prints out the following result

```
https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded
```

Which is acceptable.

The script is being run on a batch file using the following method

```
@echo off
PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://yoursite.com/tags.php?url=https://www.banggood.com/TKEXUN-M2-Flip-Phone-2800mAh-3_0-inch-Touch-Screen-Blutooth-FM-Dual-Sim-Card-Flip-Feature-Phone-p-1367504.html')"
PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://yoursite.com/tags.php?url=https://www.banggood.com/Xiaomi-Mi-9T-Pro-Global-Version-6_39-inch-48MP-Triple-Camera-NFC-4000mAh-6GB-64GB-Snapdragon-855-Octa-core-4G-Smartphone-p-1547570.html?ID=564486&cur_warehouse=HK')"
PowerShell -Command "(new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('http://yoursite.com/tags.php?url=https://www.banggood.com/OnePlus-7-6_41-Inch-FHD-AMOLED-Waterdrop-Display-60Hz-NFC-3700mAh-48MP-Rear-Camera-8GB-256GB-UFS-3_0-Snapdragon-855-Octa-Core-4G-Smartphone-p-1499559.html?ID=62208216150349&cur_warehouse=HK')"
```

That in return prints out on the screen the resulting links or when pipe'd on a file to a file, 
[image: screenshot]
it also works with list of urls on a file on another batch script, but it doesn't matter now

**The problem i'm experiencing is**

When i try to fetch the og:image links of links like from gearbest website
for example this one

```
https://www.gearbest.com/headsets/pp_009839056462.html
```

**I get no results!!!**

I've run simple commands like `wget -qO- url` or `curl -I url` for headers and the result is that it has something to do with how my php was compiled, or even curls, on the SSL side.
I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53127113/php-curl-headers-do-not-return-from-website) that some sites need newer secure ssl etc.

To be noted i've also tried *masquerading* the wget request by changing *user agent* and other cookie related values on the fly, but still with **no** success.

I'm on a shared hosting with shell access on a jailed shell but with many binary tools, sed/awk/wget/curl etc and the host site is quite helpful in helping me resolve my problems by adding binaries i may need, but still i don't know how to proceed.

**Any help is greatly appreciated**

Answer (score 2):

You're probably blocked due to your user-agent. I tried a curl to gearbest as well, and got a 403 permission denied error. Akamai seems to be blocking this user-agent.

But when I used something like `curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" URL` it worked fine.

Comment: i've tried running it on a script inside my host shell with the following as example  
curl -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (K HTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" -O "https://www.gearbest.com/headsets/pp_009839056462.html"  
with no success the curl doesn't give results. Still curl headers may be the way but i need to impletent it on my script above that prints out the array and from that keeps only the image, so i may need to change the way php works in my example, and instead of file_get_contents load a curl pipe.

Comment: maybe it worked for you @George cause your current setup has also the latest curl build with latest SSL. The curl i'm currently using and get no results is curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.27.1 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2 Protocols: tftp ftp telnet dict ldap ldaps http file https ftps scp sftp Features: GSS-Negotiate IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz

Comment: I've just tested it using the latest curl binary for windows, 7.66.0, that i downloaded and made the script into a batch file.. and it works, it displays the result on the screen as expected of the masquerading. I will try to run this version of the binary on my host shell and report back!!